# JavaScript object number format

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to iterate through an array of objects and change the string values into number. Here is an example:

I'm working with a data format similar to the variable below. I'm passing this array to a kendo chart and it can't read the values for `displayAd_imp`, `videoAd_imp`, `tv_imp` because they are string and some contains "," as well.

```
var objArr = [{

    "Title": "July 13 - July 19 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "3,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "1.5",
        "tv_imp": "0.52",
        "Date": "2014-07-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 29
}, {

    "Title": "July 20 - July 26 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,600",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.55",
        "tv_imp": "0.052",
        "Date": "2014-07-24T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 30
}, {

    "Title": "July 27 - Aug 2 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.1",
        "tv_imp": "0.122",
        "Date": "2014-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 31
}, {

    "Title": "Aug 3 - Aug 9 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "1.99",
        "tv_imp": "0.254",
        "Date": "2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 32
}, {

    "Title": "Aug 10 - Aug 17 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,400",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.0",
        "tv_imp": ".235",
        "Date": "2014-08-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 33
}];
```

Below is the function I'm trying to write that iterates over each key but I'm having some trouble with changing the format. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7bevxc/) example.

```
//looping over the array
for(var i in objArr){
    var g = objArr[i]
    for(var n in g){
         if(g.hasOwnProperty(n)){
            //I'm trying to remove the "," from the string below. 
            //g[n] = g[n].replace(/,/g,"");
            console.log("**********************************")
            console.log(n, " - ",typeof(n), " - ", g[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope the question and example is clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: You're misusing `for..in`. You should loop arrays with a regular `for` loop, or simply use `map`, as that's what you're doing after all.

Comment: @elclanrs While you _should_ use a regular `for` loop for an array, there's nothing in JavaScript that says that you _can't_ use a `for..in` loop.

Comment: What is the "trouble" you are talking about?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9x7bevxc/1/

Answer (score 0):

The replace function is much simpler that you probably are thinking - it doesn't require regexes. The following will work to replace the commas with nothing:

```
g[n] = g[n].replace(",", "");
```

As for converting the string to an int, you can use `parseInt`

```
g[n] = parseInt(g[n]);
```

Combining these:

```
g[n] = parseInt(g[n].replace(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change strings to numbers via `parseInt(yourVariabe)` or `Number(yourVariable);`

Comment: It should be okay now.

Answer (score 0):

Only apply the regex to the correct values, and use `parseFloat` to parse the numbers:

```
var toReplace = ["displayAd_imp", "videoAd_imp", "tv_imp"];
```

and later in the code

```
if(toReplace.indexOf(n) > -1) {
  g[n] = parseFloat(g[n].replace(/,/g, ""));
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8w8suo0/

Comment: What if the OP doesn't know what the variables will look like beforehand?

Comment: That is out of scope, since the question explicitly stated that the relevant keys are `displayAd_imp, videoAd_imp, tv_imp`.

Answer (score 0):

Messing about in Firefox's scratchpad for a few minutes got me to this:

```
for (i in objArr) {
  var g = objArr[i];
  for (n in g) {
    if (!/-/.test(g[n])) {
      try {
        try {
          g[n] = parseInt(g[n].replace(",",''),10);
        } catch (e) {
          g[n] = parseFloat(g[n].replace(",",''),10);
        }
      } catch(e) {}
    }
  }
  for (n in g) console.log(n + '\t:\t' + g[n]);
}
```

If there's a `-` in the existing value, it skips. Otherwise, it tries to parse an integer, and, failing that, a float in the value (removing any commas that may be there).  If it can't parse an integer or a float. it leaves the value alone.